# Don't show issue for particular user group in zabbix

Tags: zabbix

I have unprivileged user group in zabbix. I make read-only access to the one server group and I want to hide some Problems|issues for them.

On the dashboard page unprivileges user see all problems as I am, but I want to hide all low level problems (disk load, processor load, ...) and stay only some hi-level errors.

It's possible? All I've found is the limitation of the sending of notifications with media. But on the dashboard the problems are still displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with the current permission model - there is a [feature request](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-77) to improve it.

You can hide lower severities with a [dashboard filter](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/web_interface/frontend_sections/monitoring/dashboard#dashboard_filter), though. As this isn't something editable from the UI, and you cannot set defaults for users, the best bet would be setting the desired filters for a single user, then copying the filter settings from that user to all other/new users on the database level. Note that users would still be free to change their filter settings afterwards, and they could see this information in all other screens.